# gvNix exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Missing context value for 'datatablesUseAjax'

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-roo, gvnix

I'm using gvNix. Tried to list all the users in the database and this error was thrown.

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [] in context with path [/] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.apache.tiles.impl.CannotRenderException: ServletException including path '/WEB-INF/layouts/default.jspx'.] with root cause
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Missing context value for 'datatablesUseAjax'
        at org.apache.jsp.tag.webdatatables.table_tagx.doTag(table_tagx.java:1070)
        at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.users.list_jspx._jspx_meth_table_005ftable_005f0(list_jspx.java:126)
        at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.users.list_jspx.access$0(list_jspx.java:108)
        at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.users.list_jspx$Helper.invoke0(list_jspx.java:269)
        at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.users.list_jspx$Helper.invoke(list_jspx.java:304)
        at org.apache.jsp.tag.webdatatables.list_tagx$Helper.invoke0(list_tagx.java:1107)
        at org.apache.jsp.tag.webdatatables.list_tagx$Helper.invoke(list_tagx.java:1125)
        at org.apache.jsp.tag.webjquery.util.panel_tagx._jspx_meth_c_005fif_005f0(panel_tagx.java:188)
        at org.apache.jsp.tag.webjquery.util.panel_tagx.doTag(panel_tagx.java:139)
        at org.apache.jsp.tag.webdatatables.list_tagx._jspx_meth_util_005fpanel_005f0(list_tagx.java:448)
        at org.apache.jsp.tag.webdatatables.list_tagx._jspx_meth_c_005fif_005f0(list_tagx.java:268)
        at org.apache.jsp.tag.webdatatables.list_tagx.doTag(list_tagx.java:232)
        at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.users.list_jspx._jspx_meth_page_005flist_005f0(list_jspx.java:103)
        at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.users.list_jspx._jspService(list_jspx.java:72)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:605)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:544)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:954)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doInclude(PageContextImpl.java:684)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.include(PageContextImpl.java:678)
        at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.include(JspTilesRequestContext.java:103)
        at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.dispatch(JspTilesRequestContext.java:96)
        at org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.TemplateAttributeRenderer.write(TemplateAttributeRenderer.java:44)
        at org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.render(AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.java:106)
        at org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.ChainedDelegateAttributeRenderer.write(ChainedDelegateAttributeRenderer.java:76)
        at org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.render(AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.java:106)
        at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:670)
        at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:336)
        at org.apache.tiles.template.InsertAttributeModel.renderAttribute(InsertAttributeModel.java:210)
        at org.apache.tiles.template.InsertAttributeModel.end(InsertAttributeModel.java:126)
        at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.doTag(InsertAttributeTag.java:311)
        at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.layouts.default_jspx._jspx_meth_tiles_005finsertAttribute_005f2(default_jspx.java:510)
        at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.layouts.default_jspx._jspService(default_jspx.java:331)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:487)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:412)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
        at org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.forward(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:241)
        at org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.dispatch(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:222)
        at org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.TemplateAttributeRenderer.write(TemplateAttributeRenderer.java:44)
        at org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.render(AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.java:106)
        at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:670)
        at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:690)
        at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:644)
        at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:627)
        at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:321)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView.renderMergedOutputModel(TilesView.java:124)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:264)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1208)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:992)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:939)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:953)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:844)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:829)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at com.github.dandelion.datatables.core.web.filter.DatatablesFilter.doFilter(DatatablesFilter.java:73)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at com.github.dandelion.datatables.core.web.filter.DatatablesFilter.doFilter(DatatablesFilter.java:73)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.java:180)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I enabled gvNix bootstrap and datatables. Also used typicalsecurity addon
It was working fine but I don't know what happened afterwards.

log.roo

```
// Spring Roo 1.3.2.RELEASE [rev d18aef8] log opened at 2015-12-11 15:20:28
project --topLevelPackage testbootstrap --projectName TestBootstrap --java 6 --packaging JAR
// Spring Roo 1.3.2.RELEASE [rev d18aef8] log closed at 2015-12-11 15:20:30
// Spring Roo 1.3.2.RELEASE [rev d18aef8] log opened at 2015-12-11 15:23:05
// [failed] typicalsecurity setup 
hint
jpa setup --database HYPERSONIC_IN_MEMORY --provider HIBERNATE 
entity jpa --class ~.domain.User --testAutomatically --permitReservedWords
field string --fieldName firstName --sizeMin 1 --notNull
field string --fieldName lastName --sizeMin 1 --notNull
field string --fieldName emailAddress --sizeMin 1 --notNull --unique
field string --fieldName password --sizeMin 1 --notNull
field date --fieldName activationDate --type java.util.Date 
field string --fieldName activationKey 
field boolean --fieldName enabled 
field boolean --fieldName locked 
entity jpa --class ~.domain.Role --testAutomatically --permitReservedWords
field string --fieldName roleName --sizeMin 1 --notNull --unique
field string --fieldName roleDescription --sizeMin --sizeMax 200 --notNull
entity jpa --class ~.domain.UserRole --testAutomatically
field reference --fieldName userEntry --type ~.domain.User --notNull
field reference --fieldName roleEntry --type ~.domain.Role --notNull
finder add findUsersByEmailAddress --class ~.domain.User
finder add findUsersByActivationKeyAndEmailAddress --class ~.domain.User
finder add findUserRolesByUserEntry --class ~.domain.UserRole
// [failed] typicalsecurity setup 
web mvc setup 
web mvc jquery setup
web mvc jquery all 
web mvc bootstrap setup
// [failed] entity jpa --class ~.domain.User --testAutomatically --permitReservedWords
field string --fieldName firstName --sizeMin 1 --notNull
field string --fieldName lastName --sizeMin 1 --notNull
field string --fieldName emailAddress --sizeMin 1 --notNull --unique
field string --fieldName password --sizeMin 1 --notNull
field date --fieldName activationDate --type java.util.Date 
field string --fieldName activationKey 
field boolean --fieldName enabled 
field boolean --fieldName locked 
// [failed] entity jpa --class ~.domain.Role --testAutomatically --permitReservedWords
field string --fieldName roleName --sizeMin 1 --notNull --unique
field string --fieldName roleDescription --sizeMin --sizeMax 200 --notNull
// [failed] entity jpa --class ~.domain.UserRole --testAutomatically
// [failed] field reference --fieldName userEntry --type ~.domain.User --notNull
// [failed] field reference --fieldName roleEntry --type ~.domain.Role --notNull
finder add findUsersByEmailAddress --class ~.domain.User
finder add findUsersByActivationKeyAndEmailAddress --class ~.domain.User
finder add findUserRolesByUserEntry --class ~.domain.UserRole
web mvc scaffold --class ~.web.UserController --backingType ~.domain.User
web mvc scaffold --class ~.web.RoleController --backingType ~.domain.Role
web mvc scaffold --class ~.web.UserRoleController --backingType ~.domain.UserRole
security setup
email sender setup --hostServer smtp.gmail.com --port 587 --protocol SMTP --username rohitsghatoltest@gmail.com --password password4me
email template setup --from rohitsghatoltest@gmail.com --subject "Password Recovery"
typicalsecurity setup 
web mvc all --package testbootstrap.web
web mvc all --package testbootstrap.domain
web mvc all --package testbootstrap.web
web mvc all --package testbootstrap.domain
web mvc jquery all 
// Spring Roo 1.3.2.RELEASE [rev d18aef8] log opened at 2015-12-12 11:27:11
osgi start --url file:///C:\Users\Motassem\Desktop\roo-i18n-arabic-master/target/org.dls.roo.i18n.arabic-0.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar
osgi start --url file:///C:\Users\Motassem\Downloads\roo-i18n-arabic-master\roo-i18n-arabic-master/target/org.dls.roo.i18n.arabic-0.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar
// Spring Roo 1.3.2.RELEASE [rev d18aef8] log closed at 2015-12-12 12:17:18
// Spring Roo 1.3.2.RELEASE [rev d18aef8] log opened at 2015-12-12 12:21:11
osgi start --url file:///C:\Users\Motassem\Downloads\roo-i18n-arabic-master\roo-i18n-arabic-master/target/org.dls.roo.i18n.arabic-0.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar
osgi start --url file:///C:\Users\Motassem\Downloads\roo-i18n-arabic-master\roo-i18n-arabic-master/target/org.dls.roo.i18n.arabic-0.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar
osgi start --url file:///C:/Users/Motassem/Downloads/roo-i18n-arabic-master/roo-i18n-arabic-master/target/org.dls.roo.i18n.arabic-0.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar
web mvc language --code ar 
web mvc datatables setup
// Spring Roo 1.3.2.RELEASE [rev d18aef8] log opened at 2015-12-17 08:04:14
web mvc datatables update tags
web mvc bootstrap update
web mvc datatables add --type ~.web.UserController --mode show
// [failed] web mvc datatables add --type ~.web.UserListController
web mvc datatables add --type ~.web.RoleController
web mvc language --code ar 
entity jpa --class ~.domain.Major 
field string --fieldName majorName --notNull --sizeMin 2
entity jpa --class ~.domain.University --testAutomatically 
field string --fieldName universityName --notNull --sizeMin 2
field string --fieldName universityAddress
entity jpa --class ~.domain.Application --testAutomatically 
web mvc all --package testbootstrap.web
web mvc datatables update tags
web mvc bootstrap update
web mvc language --code ar 
// Spring Roo 1.3.2.RELEASE [rev d18aef8] log closed at 2015-12-17 10:30:40
// Spring Roo 1.3.2.RELEASE [rev d18aef8] log opened at 2015-12-20 13:16:55
// Spring Roo 1.3.2.RELEASE [rev d18aef8] log closed at 2015-12-20 13:53:35
// Spring Roo 1.3.2.RELEASE [rev d18aef8] log opened at 2015-12-22 11:14:34
jpa setup --database MYSQL --provider HIBERNATE 
// Spring Roo 1.3.2.RELEASE [rev d18aef8] log closed at 2015-12-22 11:34:24
// Spring Roo 1.3.2.RELEASE [rev d18aef8] log opened at 2015-12-22 11:48:29
web mvc all --package edu.gju.edusyria.web
// Spring Roo 1.3.2.RELEASE [rev d18aef8] log closed at 2015-12-22 11:57:13
// Spring Roo 1.3.2.RELEASE [rev d18aef8] log opened at 2015-12-22 11:59:05
// [failed] perform eclipse
// Spring Roo 1.3.2.RELEASE [rev d18aef8] log closed at 2015-12-22 12:19:19
// Spring Roo 1.3.2.RELEASE [rev d18aef8] log opened at 2015-12-22 12:19:33
focus --class ~.domain.Application
field string --fieldName status 
// Spring Roo 1.3.2.RELEASE [rev d18aef8] log closed at 2015-12-22 14:18:06
// Spring Roo 1.3.2.RELEASE [rev d18aef8] log opened at 2015-12-22 14:43:34
// Spring Roo 1.3.2.RELEASE [rev d18aef8] log closed at 2015-12-22 15:01:28
// Spring Roo 1.3.2.RELEASE [rev d18aef8] log opened at 2015-12-23 09:03:32
// [failed] entity jpa --class ~.domain.User --testAutomatically --permitReservedWords
// [failed] entity jpa --class ~.domain.Role --testAutomatically --permitReservedWords
// [failed] entity jpa --class ~.domain.UserRole --testAutomatically
finder add findUsersByEmailAddress --class ~.domain.User
finder add findUsersByActivationKeyAndEmailAddress --class ~.domain.User
finder add findUserRolesByUserEntry --class ~.domain.UserRole
web mvc scaffold --class ~.web.UserController --backingType ~.domain.User
web mvc scaffold --class ~.web.RoleController --backingType ~.domain.Role
web mvc scaffold --class ~.web.UserRoleController --backingType ~.domain.UserRole
email sender setup --hostServer smtp.gmail.com --port 587 --protocol SMTP --username rohitsghatoltest@gmail.com --password password4me
email template setup --from rohitsghatoltest@gmail.com --subject "Password Recovery"
typicalsecurity setup
web mvc all --package edu.gju.edusyria.web
web mvc all --package edu.gju.edusyria.domain
web mvc datatables update tags
web mvc all --package edu.gju.edusyria.web
web mvc bootstrap update
osgi start --url file:///C:/Users/Motassem/Desktop/roo-i18n-arabic-master/target/org.dls.roo.i18n.arabic-0.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar
web mvc language --code ar 
// Spring Roo 1.3.2.RELEASE [rev d18aef8] log closed at 2015-12-23 10:43:36
// Spring Roo 1.3.2.RELEASE [rev d18aef8] log opened at 2015-12-23 13:07:17
// [failed] web mvc datatables add --type ~.domain.University 
// [failed] web mvc datatables all 
web mvc jquery all
web mvc datatables all 
// Spring Roo 1.3.2.RELEASE [rev d18aef8] log closed at 2015-12-23 13:37:46
```

Comment: Could you provide your `log.roo` to be able to test your issue?